# The table size in the pdf is not the same in the webpage

Tags: javascript, html, css

The table size in the pdf is not the same in the webpage.

I have many table on my html webpage . The table are filled by a lot of long data For example, a textarea with 30 column and 20 row.
However, the pdf crop the table into 10 column and 15 row. Initial part of the data is correct but rest of the data is excluded.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2pdf.js/0.9.2/html2pdf.bundle.js"></script>


window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("generatepdf").addEventListener("click", function () {
        var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".status-checkbox");
        var checkboxes2 = document.querySelectorAll(".status-checkbox2");
        var isChecked = false;
        var isChecked2 = false;
    
    for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            isChecked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < checkboxes2.length; i2++) {  // Note the corrected loop variable name (i2 instead of i)
        if (checkboxes2[i2].checked) {
            isChecked2 = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if (!isChecked) {
        alert("At least one checkbox from Kursus Yang Diajar must be checked.");
    } else {
        if (!isChecked2) {
            alert("At least one checkbox from Tugas-Tugas Pengurusan must be checked.");
        } else {
            // At least one checkbox is checked, proceed to generate the PDF
               var cv = document.getElementById("cv").cloneNode(true);

            // Remove all elements with the class name "addrow1" from the cloned content
                var skillsDivs = cv.querySelectorAll(".addrow1");
                skillsDivs.forEach(function (skillsDiv) {
                skillsDiv.remove();
            });
                var checkboxes = cv.querySelectorAll(".print-hidden");
                checkboxes.forEach(function (checkbox) {
                checkbox.remove();
            });
            // Select all input fields with placeholders
                var inputFields = cv.querySelectorAll("input[placeholder]");

            // Hide the placeholder text for each input field
                inputFields.forEach(function (inputField) {
                inputField.placeholder = "";
            });

            var opt = {
                margin: 1,
                filename: 'cv.pdf',
                image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
                html2canvas: { scale: 5 },
                jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: [8.27, 11.69], orientation: 'portrait' },
                pagebreak: { avoid: 'table' },
                pagebreak: { avoid: 'tr' }
            };

            html2pdf().from(cv).set(opt).save();
        }
    }
});
```

};